# Что лучше использовать и как обойти ограничения

Tags: mysql

Есть Веб приложение (ASP NET MVC), которое досталось на поддержку.
Часть по аутентификации использует подключение к базе MS SQL Server Expres.
Основная часть приложения, использует БД My SQL Commynity.
Конечно чтобы не тратить деньги никто в организации не хочет вкладываться в нормальную версию MS SQL Server.
вопрос (по части MY SQL), есть ли ограничение в MySQL на идентификаторы в базе данных?
Поясню, есть таблица, столбцы int(11) identity 1,1, varchar(255)......
Первый столбец автоинкремент. С ним вопрос, у него длина 2147483647, как только достигнут значения в БД такого количества, что произойдет с данными? вставка в БД будет невозможна? или будут перезаписываться? как в данном случае ведет себя MySQL ?
Решения проблемы: использовать BIGINT или UNSIGNED BIGINT, но они тоже конечны ?
Или есть другие способы решения?

Если перевести все таблицы в MSSQL Server Express, как лучше обойти ограничение в 10Гб ?

Comment: Есть вариант использовать float или double, но они тоже конечны. Но это ужасная идея использовать эти типы для первичного ключа, а тем более в качестве идентификатора.

Comment: да не float/double конечно не хотелось бы

Comment: Стоит также подумать, правильно ли спроектирована БД, если требуется больше 8 байт. А ещё уточнить, сколько по времени будет наполняться таблица с 18446744073709551616 записями.

Comment: Что это у вас за данные такие, что вам даже bigint не хватает? :)

Comment: float/double нельзя использовать в качестве первичного ключа, т.к. во-первых, значение может искажаться, а, во-вторых, они хранят меньше уникальных значений чем int/bigint соответственно.

Comment: у int не 2147483647 уникальных значений, а в два раза больше. Отрицательные значения id такие же допустимые, как и положительные

Comment: Всем спасибо большое за участие в вопросе. Конечно же bigint хватить с головой. Просто было интересно, может в mysql /mssql что-то еще можно было придумать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Решения проблемы: использовать BIGINT или UNSIGNED BIGINT, но они тоже конечны ?

Возьмите калькулятор, посчитайте с какой скоростью вам надо писать данные, чтобы хотя бы за нереальные для срока жизни приложения 50 лет вы их исчерпали.

```
select pow(2,63)/50/365.25/24/60/60;
5845420460.906264
```

Почти 6 миллиардов строк в секунду? У вас серьёзно есть столько данных? А где вы их хранить собираетесь?

> у него длина 2147483647, как только достигнут значения в БД такого количества, что произойдет с данными?

Если говорить об AUTO_INCREMENT - новые строки будет невозможно вставить из-за нарушения ограничения первичного ключа, т.к. AUTO_INCREMENT требует быть уникальным.

Интересное исключение - если вы используете `insert on duplicate key update` - вы получите нарушение первичного ключа при попытке `insert` и потому будет запускаться `update` последней строки. Хотя в 8.0 может и изменили поведение. На 5.6 последний раз проверял.

---

Кстати, у MS SQL ровно те же самые лимиты на генерацию последовательностей: identity ограничен размером типа данных. Int и bigint ровно такие же как в mysql.

Comment: Спасибо  вам большое! сам не догадался до калькулятора. Таких данных конечно же нет. В месяц всего пара десятков миллионов записей, в текущем проекте.